# Camping's path building method

Tags: ruby, syntax, camping

Could someone explain for me this part of the code from Lucky Stiff's Camping micro-framework:

```
# Simply builds a complete path from a path +p+ within the app.  If your
# application is mounted at <tt>/blog</tt>:
#
#   self / "/view/1"    #=> "/blog/view/1"
#   self / "styles.css" #=> "styles.css"
#   self / R(Edit, 1)   #=> "/blog/edit/1"
#
def /(p); p[0] == ?/ ? @root + p : p end
```

[Source](https://github.com/camping/camping/blob/master/lib/camping-unabridged.rb#L209)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def /(p);
```

method name is '**/**' which receives the parameter '**p**'

```
p[0] == ?/
```

check if the string starts with a '**/**'. Question mark is used to specify that the character is being used literally. You can also consider it same as '/'

```
p[0] == ?/ ? exp1:exp2
```

The second question mark is for conditional evaluation. If the expression(p[0] == ?/) is true then evaluate exp1 else evaluate exp2.

So in the above case if the string parameter starts with a **'/'** then return the value @root + p, that is prepend it with root. On the other if the parameter does not start with a **'/'** then return it as such.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. The question mark operator confused me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to write it:

```
def /(p)
  if p[0] == ?/
    @root + p
  else
    p
  end
end
```

`p[0]`returns the first character in the string. `?/` returns the `/` character. Note that in 1.8 a character is represented by an integer (`?/ == 47`) while in 1.9 it's a one-character string (`?/ == "/"`). Nonetheless, `p[0]` will always be consistent with `?/`.

So on a higher level, it checks if the first character in the string is a slash, if so it prepends the `@root` (which is set in Camping::Base#initialize) to it.

So if your application is mounted at /blog, `@root == "/blog"` and `self / "/post/1" == "/blog/post/1"`.